# Debug logic in find statement

Tags: ruby

I have a problem with the `find` statement. I have an array of `stuff`. I searched for a specific item, and did not find it. How do I debug to know what condition inside the `find` statement is failing?

```
array.find {|x| (x.a == ::stuff::stuffiesA || x.a == ::stuff::stuffiesB) &&
                 x.b == thing &&
                 x.c == ::stuff::thingies}
```

Comment: extract statments to variables, combining them on the last line and step through

Comment: sounds like a good idea! where can i learn how to do it?

Comment: I stated earlier that i am new to ruby and that it is hard to find anything on google when you search for "ruby find" and even harder to find anything with combinde logic inside. plz motivate your downvotes!

Comment: in any introduction book to programming...

Comment: I know how to do it in C, C++, Java, but not in Ruby. My environment is not so forgiving so i cant just brute force test to get an awnser..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be too much for the comments, so reposting:

Usually I extract the statements to variables and step through. Most IDEs have shortcuts for variable extraction. The one from RubyMine is `Ctrl+Alt+V`

After extraction, it could look like this:

```
array.find {|x| 
  xa_eq_stuffies_a = (x.a == ::stuff::stuffiesA)
  xa_eq_stuffies_b = (x.a == ::stuff::stuffiesB)
  xb_eq_thing = (x.b == thing)
  xc_eq_thingies = (x.c == thing)

  (xa_eq_stuffies_a || xa_eq_stuffies_b) &&
  xb_eq_thing && xc_eq_thingies
}
```

Then you can properly debug it.

You can also use the [**tap()**](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Object.html#method-i-tap) method (requires ruby >= 1.9) to preserve the code structure, but I would refactor that train-wreck anyway :)

Comment: Before even going into the logic, expressions like `::stuff::stuffiesA` are ungrammatical in Ruby. So the whole code should not run in the first place.

Comment: @sawa - you're most certainly right, I'm not so good with ruby yet :) since I'm not sure what prefixed :: stand for (global namespace?) I ignored them in the answer

Answer (score 1):

if you are using an IDE use the watch window to get the result of each of the expressions. E.g. put `x.a == ::stuff::stuffiesA` as an expression in the watch window and then set a break point.

or you could alter the source slightly to make it easier for you

```
array.find {|x|
         a = x.a == ::stuff::stuffiesA 
         b = x.a == ::stuff::stuffiesB
         c = x.b == thing
         d = x.c == ::stuff::thingies
           (a || b) &&
            c &&
            d}
```

of course you should use appropriate names for the variables which will not only help you debug but also make the code easier to understand